# How can I convert 4 bytes storing an IEEE 754 floating point number to a float value in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

My program reads into 4 bytes an IEEE 754 floating point number from a file. I need to portable convert those bytes to my C compilers float type. In other words I need a function with the prototype `float IEEE_754_to_float(uint8_t raw_value[4])` for my C program.

Comment: There isn't going to be a 100% portable way due to endianness. But I bet you can get away with just a simple `union`.

Comment: @Mysticial, I was wondering about that. I know that there is a 100% portable way to accomplish this for big endian integer numbers. Why should floating point be any different?

Comment: Well, for one, you can't shift floating-point numbers. So you can't really "construct" a floating-point value byte-by-byte using just floating-point operations.

Comment: @Mysticial, but a floating point number is just a number to the power of another number, and a sign bit. Isn't it possible to just do `sign_bit * powf(x, y)`?

Comment: You *could* do it that way. Probably not the best idea if performance matters. (You'd also have to check for infinities and NaN...) But the other issue is the endian of the input bytes. So I can't see any way other than to use preprocessor to check the endian and then choose the appropriate implementation.

Comment: @Mysticial, the 4 bytes are big endian. Also, exactly why, and how would I need to handle infinities and NaN?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16173/discussion-between-steven-stewart-gallus-and-mysticial)

Answer (score 5):

If your implementation can guarantee correct endianness:

```
float raw2ieee(uint8_t *raw)
{
    // either
    union {
        uint8_t bytes[4];
        float fp;
    } un;
    memcpy(un.bytes, raw, 4);
    return un.fp;

    // or, as seen in the fast inverse square root:
    return *(float *)raw;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the endianness is the same, then like so:

```
float f;
memcpy(&f, raw_value, sizeof f);
return f;
```

If not, say:

```
float f;
char * p = (char *)&f;
```

And now populate the bytes `p[0]`... manually as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that portable transforms an IEEE_754 number to one's C compiler's float value. This code works but the loop to get the value of the fraction is is ugly, and can be done better. As well, this code does not handle special cases like infinity, and not a number.

```
float IEEE_754_to_float(const uint8_t raw[4]) {
        int sign = (raw[0] >> 7) ? -1 : 1;

        int8_t exponent = (raw[0] << 1) + (raw[1] >> 7) - 126;

        uint32_t fraction_bits = ((raw[1] & 0x7F) << 16) + (raw[2] << 8) + raw[3];

        float fraction = 0.5f;
        for (uint8_t ii = 0; ii < 24; ++ii)
                fraction += ldexpf((fraction_bits >> (23 - ii)) & 1, -(ii + 1));

        float significand = sign * fraction;

        return ldexpf(significand, exponent);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to process each fraction bit separately. Simply define `float fraction = 1<<23 | fraction_bits;` and adjust the exponent in the final ldexpf. (Omit the `1<<23` if the raw exponent is zero, to handle denormals). Any 24-bit integer can be converted to IEEE 754 float without error. (Also, your loop includes an iteration where ii is 23, which has no effect, since bit 23 of your fraction_bits is 0.)