# Converting a large integer to a floating point number in C

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, type-conversion, ieee-754

I recently wrote a block of code that takes as an input an 8 digit hexadecimal number from the user, transforms it into an integer and then converts it into a float. To go from integer to float I use the following:

```
int myInt;          
float myFloat;
myFloat = *(float *)&myInt;
printf("%g", myFloat);
```

It works perfectly for small numbers. But when the user inputs hexadecimal numbers such as:

```
0x0000ffff
0x7eeeeeef
```

I get that myInt = -2147483648 and that myFloat = -0. I know that the number I get for myInt is the smallest possible number that can be stored in an int variable in C.

Because of this problem, the input range of my program is extremely limited. Does anyone have any advice on how I could expand the range of my code so that it could handle a number as big as:

```
0xffffffff
```

Thank you so much for any help you may give me!

Comment: what is in `intToFloat` ?

Comment: If you want to accurately represent the full range of a 32 bit int then you'll need to use `double` rather than `float`, since `float` only has around 23-24 bits of precision.

Comment: Sorry about the intoToFloat. I modified my variable names so that they would not be out of context but I forgot to change that one.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use a double because the point of the program is to take an 8-digit hexadecimal number to its floating point single precision representation (IEEE 754). Would using a double change that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'take hex number to its floating point single precision representation'? Do you mean that you want to treat the bit pattern stored in the integer as if it is a `float`? That's roughly what your code does at the moment. If that is what you want, then you primarily need to sort out your integer conversion code; you should be able to print the hex value from the integer and get the same value as you entered, but if you get 0x80000000 (-2147483648) as the output, your conversion is wrong.  Which compiler are you using, on which platform? Beware if `sizeof(int) == 2` (unlikely).

Comment: You might also look at [How can I convert 4 bytes storing an IEEE 754 floating point number to a `float` value in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242187/how-can-i-convert-4-bytes-storing-an-ieee-754-floating-point-number-to-a-float-v)

Comment: Incidentally, it is not proper C to convert between integer and float representations using pointer aliasing. Proper ways are either to copy bytes (as with `memcpy`) or to use a union, such as `MyFloat = (union { unsigned int u; float f; }) { MyUnsignedInt } .f;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to get the value transferred as accurately as `float` will allow is:

```
float myFloat = myInt;
```

If you want better accuracy, use `double` instead of `float`.

What you're doing is trying to reinterpret the bit pattern for the `int` as if it was a `float`, which is not a good idea.  There are hexadecimal floating-point constants and conversions available in C99 and later.  (However, if that's what you are trying, your code in the question is correct — your problem appears to be in converting hex to integer.)

If you get `-2147483648` from 0x0000FFFF (or from 0x7EEEFFFF), there is a bug in your conversion code.  Fix that before doing anything else.  How are you doing the hex to integer conversion? Using [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) is probably a good way (and [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html)
 and friends is also possible), but be careful about overflows.)

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do (reinterpreting the bit pattern for the int as if it was a float). To go from hex to int I simply loop through the hexadecimal number received from the user and multiply each digit by powers if 16, starting at 16^0 on the rightmost bit and finishing with 16^7. I add every result as the loop goes through and end up with one integer.

Comment: OK.  If you enter 0x0000FFFF and get 0x80000000 out of your code, your conversion code has a problem.  That seems to be what you're saying in your question. (If it is not what you mean, you need to clarify the question — and it might not be a bad idea to clarify that this is what you're doing anyway.) At the very least, you must validate that you're getting the correct value out of your hex conversion code.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any advice on how I could expand the range of my code so that it could
>       handle a number as big as `0xffffffff`

You can't store 0xffffffff in a 32-bit `int`; the largest positive hex value you can store in a 32 bit `int` is 0x7FFFFFFF or (2^31 -1) or 2147483647, but the negative range is -2^31 or -2147483648,

The ranges are due to obvious limitations in the number of bits available and the 2's complement system.

Use an `unsigned int` if you want 0xffffffff.

Comment: I decided to use strtol() instead of the method I wrote to convert the hexadecimal input to an integer. Now I am storing the value that strtol() gives me in a uint32_t but it only works for numbers smaller than or equal to 0x7effffff (which is an improvement since it only used to work for numbers smaller than or equal to 0x7eeeeeee). Is this as far as I can go Jonathan? Or is it possible to expand the range even further?